# Sony Vegas Pro 12 Render issue

Tags: video, editing, sony-vegas

I have been having the most frustrating issue with Sony Vegas in relation to rendering in 720p as of late.

My original system 
Win7 32 bit
4 gigs of DDR2 Ram
8600 GT Graphics Card
AMD 965 Quad Core.

For the longest time my system could and would render videos properly, no issues, sure the render times may be a tad bit long but the videos came out great!

Then it happened, the videos Id render in WMV would become choppy...oddly enough it was consistent across ALL videos Id render in 720p. The video itself looked great but the file when played (And no isnt some kind of codec issue during playback as the file maintained the choppy-ness after being uploaded) would become incredibly choppy.

Now, I had plans to update mysystem so I took it as maybe some setting in Sony vegas had gotten borked so I held off.

Fastfoward to now...

Win7 Pro 64bit
GTX 650 Graphics Card
Same Processor Clocked to 3.8 GHZ
SSD Boot Drive
16 Gigs of DDR 3 Ram Clocked at 1600 (Stock Clocked)

Clearly the system has improved, so I upgraded to Vegas 12, and was sure my issue would be fixed. Lo and behold...it wasnt...

I'm tearing my hair out at this point, if anyone can help it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try...

1. Disable GPU acceleration, using 32-bit mode if you're in 64-bit and
   vice versa.
2. Running Vegas in Windows compatibility mode may resolve some issues.
   Right click on the Vegas launch icon, and select properties, then
   click the compatibility tab. Place a check in the box -- "Run this
   program in compatibilty mode for...".